# Not saving ClientID in Address

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

##### Client

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "cpf", nullable = false)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "registration_data")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", timezone = "GMT") //ISO 8601
    private Date registrationData;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientId")
    private List<Contact> contacts;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clientId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pets")
    private List<Pet> pets;

    @Column(name = "type_profile", nullable = false)
    private String typeProfile;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;
}
```

##### Address

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientId")
    private Client clientId;

    @Column(name = "publicPlace")
    private String publicPlace;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "district")
    private String district;

    @Column(name = "complement")
    private String complement;

    @Column(name = "tag")
    private String tag;
}
```

I tried messing with the one to many relationships but it didn't work.

None of the relations are working as expected, saving the id.

In the database saves only the first object without having the cascade of adding the ID in the related table.

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, because it saves the object and creates the ID in the table, but it doesn't associate as a cascade in the second object.

Answer (score 0):

Shall you change to the following code ,and use the client.getId() to use the client id?
You hava to ensure the table in you database named client is exist

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    private Client client;
```